# AIR SocketServer mobile app and policy file

Tags: sockets, air

Building an AIR based mobile application which will only be used over a local wifi network.

The SocketServer class will be used to load and save high scores.

Will I need to make use of a policy file?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, pretty much if you are requesting a resource from anywhere other than the same port and host as where the .swf came from you will probably need a policy server and a crossdomain file.

Edit: The reason for this is security. Imagine you are working at a corperate office behind a firewall browsing the web. A malicious flash ad is on a site you are visiting and starts copying intranet files from your browser (which is behind the firewall) and uploading them to a secret location. The policy server ensures that servers you access want you to access them, and can specify what exactly you are allowed to access.